# Not able to accept browser based pop up using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, popup

I'm stucked in one problem.In my site,I need to accept "***Allow camera***" pop up. i have tried with the below code,but i'm getting "**`TimeoutException`**" **error**,although the Pop up has been shown successfully,But it is not recognizing it.

```
try     
{        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);        
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());    
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();    
        System.out.println(alert.getText());    
        alert.accept();    

    } 
 catch (Exception e)   
    {    
        //exception handling    
        e.printStackTrace();     
    }
```

Please refer the attached screenshot for Pop Up.
[Browser based Pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lozMJ.png)

Thanks,

Comment: give a try Driver.switch to window() with proper delay

Comment: Okay.Thanks !! Let me try it and i'll get back to you. :-)

Comment: Didn't work out !! i got "**java.util.NoSuchElementException**" error while tried to switch window.

Comment: please provide HTML of pop up

Comment: I am not able to   locate element for that pop up. :-(     When i do right click on that ,no action performed.

Comment: I tried to switch window via below code ,but script failed at   "String popupWindowId=iter.next(); " line.                                              
                                                                                                                          {
   Set<String> windowids = driver.getWindowHandles();
   Iterator<String> iter = windowids.iterator();
   String mainWindowId=iter.next();
   System.out.print(mainWindowId);
   String popupWindowId=iter.next();
   driver.switchTo().window(popupWindowId);
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

try to locate the popup and click on it or Try to implement the following code

driver.switch().alert().dismiss();